# How can $V$ be a vector space over the field of real numbers when it is explicitly defined as being over the field of complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V = \{(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n): a_i \in \mathbb{C}$ for $ i = 1, 2, .., n\}$; so $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Is V a vector space over the field of real numbers with the operations of coordinatewise addition and multiplication?

The solution says,

> Yes. All the conditions are preserved when the field is the real
>   numbers.

I don't understand how $V$ can be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$? $V$ itself is specified as being over the field of complex numbers ($V = \{(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n): a_i \in \mathbb{C}$), so how can the question then claim that $V$ is a vector space over the real numbers?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to clarify my misunderstanding.

Comment: So, colloquially speaking, you take your complex vector space, and then "forget" all the non-real scalar multiplications.  In category theory we have the "forgetful functor" for situations like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the definition of a vector space over a field, for example on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition

Being over $\mathbb{R}$ means that vectors can be multiplied by real numbers and you get again a vector in $V$. This is certainly true in your example since complex numbers multiplied by real numbers are again complex numbers.

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense. The set itself contains complex elements, but the field that the set is over is itself the real numbers. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the field that the set is over is itself the real numbers". The point is that a vector space being defined over some field $F$ means that there is an operation for multiplying vectors with elements in $F$. In the example you gave, you can define such operation for the field of real numbers, but also for complex or rational numbers since $\mathbb{C}$ is closed under multiplication by such numbers.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the assistance.